# Binary Permutation Table Becomes Too Large When # of Obs is greater than 26

Tags: r, permutation

I have a data set with 16 observations currently. I have binary treatment assignments (currently 8 control, 8 treatment). I need to derive all the possible different treatment assignments for this data set that still ends with 8 control and 8 treatment. I am currently generating all the possible permutations of 0 and 1 for 16 observations and filtering for 8 control or 8 treatment. Unfortunately, if I need to do more than 26 observations (the magic number, I believe), the data frame becomes too large for R. Is there any way to create a permutation table without the hassle of replicating all possibilities and filtering it in the middle as in the code below.

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(random)
    library(data.table)

    test <- tibble("obs"=1:16,
    "treatment"=c(rep(0,8),rep(1,8)),
    "outcome"=randomNumbers(x,0,50,1))

    treated <- sum(test$treatment)

    perm <- do.call(CJ, replicate(16,0:1, FALSE))
    perm <- perm %>% mutate(check=rowSums(perm)) %>% filter(., check == treated)
    perm$check <- NULL
    perm <- as_tibble(transpose(perm))
```

Comment: Do think about your goals and whether you really need to generate **all** the combinations. Your method is super inefficient, so it is feasible to go a *little bit* higher than 26 with a more efficient algorithm, but already at 26 choose 13 the result size is > 10M. If you get up to 30 choose 15, that's > 100M. At 34 choose 17, 2.3 **b**illion possibilities. I can't really imagine you're doing anything useful with *all* of the results. Maybe it's enough to sample 1M combinations randomly, regardless of the total number possible.

Answer (score 1):

The columns of the 8 by 12870 `co` matrix are the possible assignments to the treatment group and the remaining items are assigned to the control.  Here 12870 equals `choose(16, 8)` , i.e. the number of ways to choose 8 items from 16 items.

```
co <- combn(16, 8)
```

For example, `co[, 1]` is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 so the first 8 items are assigned to the treatment group and the last 8 are controls if that column is chosen.

Comment: This is great. I can use this with an ifelse to generate the new assignments. Thank you.